# Plotting a hydrograph-precipitation plot

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I have two numpy arrays which I would like to plot:

```
runoff = np.array([1,4,5,6,7,8,9]) 
precipitation = np.array([4,5,6,7,3,3,7])
```

The precipitation array should come from the top as bars. The runoff as line on the bottom part of the plot. Both have to different axis on the left and the right side. It kind of hard to describe that plot so I just add a link of a plot I found searching with google pics.

[Universtity of Jena, Hydrograph plot](http://www.geoinf.uni-jena.de/wetlands/grafics/ap3_04.jpg)

I could do it with R but I would like to learn it with the matplotlib module and now I am kind of stuck ...

Comment: if you can already solve this in R perhaps you should do so? If you want to learn matplotlib then the [tutorial](http://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html) is a good place to start and the [gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html) has plenty of examples.   To start with, try http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/two_scales.html (multiple data scales) and  http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/barchart_demo.html (plotting bars)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an idea:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

runoff = np.array([1,4,5,6,7,8,9]) 
precipitation = np.array([4,5,6,7,3,3,7])


fig, ax = plt.subplots()

# x axis to plot both runoff and precip. against
x = np.linspace(0, 10, len(runoff))

ax.plot(x, runoff, color="r")

# Create second axes, in order to get the bars from the top you can multiply 
# by -1
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(x, -precipitation, 0.1)

# Now need to fix the axis labels
max_pre = max(precipitation)
y2_ticks = np.linspace(0, max_pre, max_pre+1)
y2_ticklabels = [str(i) for i in y2_ticks]
ax2.set_yticks(-1 * y2_ticks)
ax2.set_yticklabels(y2_ticklabels)

plt.show()
```

[image]

There are certainly better ways to do this and from @Pierre_GM's answer it looks like there is a ready made way which is probably better.

Comment: Thanks you for your help... I used your solution for now but will take a deeper look into the hydroclimpy module.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind reading code and figure it out yourself:
http://hydroclimpy.sourceforge.net/plotlib.flows.html#plotting-hydrographs

Note that `scikits.timeseries` is no longer supported, and that `scikits.hydroclimpy` isn't either. Therefore, it's not a key-in-hand solution.
Nevertheless, reading the code should give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

@Greg Greg's answer is good. However, you usually do not need to invert the y axis and fix the axis labels manually. Just replace the following code in Greg's answer

```
# Now need to fix the axis labels
max_pre = max(precipitation)
y2_ticks = np.linspace(0, max_pre, max_pre+1)
y2_ticklabels = [str(i) for i in y2_ticks]
ax2.set_yticks(-1 * y2_ticks)
ax2.set_yticklabels(y2_ticklabels)
```

with one-line code:

```
plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
```